# HERE-API: What date-time is used if Time-aware feature is disabled?

Tags: here-api

I'm using the HERE API for routing, and am wondering: what date and time is used if the Time-aware feature is not active.

Is the time at the time of query, or the average time across the day, or something else altogether?

Furthermore, when a TrafficTime is returned (again, without Time-aware feature being active), what time is used? Is it average traffic for the past year, peak traffic last year, peak traffic ever?

Would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide departure time and traffic is disabled then the route provided will be based on the route type only and departure time will be defaulted to now(e.g: mode=fastest parameter will provide fastest route possible for a given transport mode).

When you enable traffic-optimized routing in your requests, the Routing API uses up-to-date traffic information to calculate the route. For example, a route calculation for the current time uses live traffic information.

When considering travel times in the future, this live traffic information is augmented with historical traffic speeds. In case of longer routes, the API combines live traffic information with historical traffic information for the later portions of the route. Routes calculated for trips in the future use historical traffic information to determine traffic speeds, and considers any long-term road closures on the route.

If the request does not include a departure time, the API assumes all current live traffic events (at the time of calculation) are valid for the entire length of the route and does not use any time-dependent information.

If traffic is enabled, departure time not set (default now): considers live traffic and road closures data (only for short trips). In case of long trips, for the initial part of the route live traffic data and for the rest Historic data is considered along with road closure data.

If traffic is enabled, departure time set to future: considers last 3 years average traffic information for that day of the week in the past.

Traffic is disabled, departure time not set(default now) or set(now/future): route provided without considering traffic data

Comment: So, to clarify, if I don't provide departure time and traffic is enabled, I will be given the drive times based on live traffic data? If so, should I expect different results if I run the simulation during rush hour vs in the middle of the night?

And when it comes to future journeys, what historical traffic speeds are used? If I want to check drive times for next Thursday 2pm, will the traffic data from last week's Thursday 2pm be used? Or will it be the average traffic of last week? Or a different method altogether?

Comment: Yes, if you don't provide a departure time it will be considered as now. Edited the answer to clarify your above doubts.